# how to make the range in my chart database dynamic

Tags: excel, vba, charts, range

I am getting data `(12)` every 5 seconds and I want to put these on a chart after the data input has stopped. I want to make the chart dynamic by reading each row separately. How do I avoid having to write each line ? I need to get the offset code in the range somehow and make it loop.

Biggest problem is that I don't know anything about writing codes, I record and try to find out like that. I have no background in IT at all.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Grafiek 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1:F2"), _
        PlotBy:=xlRows
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1:F1,A3:F3"), _
        PlotBy:=xlRows
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1:F1,A4:F4"), _
        PlotBy:=xlRows
```

I want the range to go up automatically (ie. a3:f3 --> a4:f4 -->...) so each row of data is put on the chart separately (I use a 1 second delay).

Answer (score 0):

The `Range` object takes a string as an argument, so you should be able to loop through your rows like such:

```
Dim intRowCount as Integer
Dim intTotalRows as Integer 'You will have to give this a value

For intRowCount = 1 to intTotalRows
    'Your 1 second delay goes here
    Dim strRangeString as String
    strRangeString = "A1:F1,A" & Trim(Str(intRowCount + 2)) & ":F" & Trim(Str(intRowCount + 2)) 'Or whatever your row offset is
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Blad1").Range(strRangeString), _
        PlotBy:=xlRows
Next intRowCount
```